# UnhandledException in .Net ActiveX Control

Tags: c#, exception, activex

I need to handle exception event from any sources in .Net ActiveX hosted on internet explorer to prevent browser crash or any exceptions occur because

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new 
       UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
```

and

```
Application.ThreadException += new 
       System.Threading.ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);
```

in Application.cs doesn't work.

Comment: Could you just surround all of your event handlers with a try/catch?

Comment: Nitipan Pompan, could you elaborate more on your issue? It's rather vague..

Comment: @JohnSaunders my all event handlers make effort more than global unhandledexception

Comment: @NitipanPompan: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @NitipanPompan Please, read [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)